# knockout mapping with computed fields

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm getting data from a WCF service,and i map, and bind the data with my DOM object :

```
var PayinyVM = {};

    $.getJSON('/service/PaidService.svc/PaidList', function (data) {
        var tmp = JSON.stringify(data.d);

        PayinyVM.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(tmp);
        ko.applyBindings(PayinyVM);
    });
```

the result is shown as excepted on my DOM bind it to model. What I couldn't find out is how to add some computed observable let's say my data is returning people with FirstName and LastName, how can I make a computed observable FullName with FN + ' ' + LN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a working copy of your fiddle, I had to make a lot of assumptions as your fiddle wasn't even correct javascript and seemed quite confused and didn't even reference knockout

```
var PaidPeople = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                    return self.Name() + " : just ";
                });
}

var PayinyVM = function (data) {
                var self = this;

                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
                    'model' : {
                        create: function(options) {
                            return new PaidPeople(options.data);
                    }                        
                  }
                }, self);                
            };

var data = {model:[{__type: "PaidPeople:#model", Amount:110, Attendee:1, Name:'John'}]};

ko.applyBindings(new PayinyVM(data)); ​
```

and a fiddle that works : http://jsfiddle.net/qeUHd/

Comment: I had tried it before, and get PayinyVM.Name is not a function. In my program actually i'm trying to add something to Name. Thanks anyway. there is version  in http://jsfiddle.net/nYF67/

Comment: well, you weren't showing that code...update your question to show that.

Comment: Which code? it's madcapnmckay answer. Basically I'd like to know once you map viewmodel to a data received how to add some computed fields base to it. Thanks

Comment: Keith what's wrong with it. that's why i put it fiddle in order for people who know knockout to correct it. Thanks anyway

Comment: your fiddle wasn't correct javascript, and didn't even have any references to the knockout library.

Comment: Thanks keith, now i have to go through your code to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can invert the mapping by creating a model object that is mapped internally.

```
var PayinyVM = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Name() + " : just ";
    });
};

$.getJSON('/service/PaidService.svc/PaidList', function (data) {    
    ko.applyBindings(new PayinyVM(data.d));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank yo very much for your help, but it doesn't work for me. I changed MyModel to PayingVM, and parse(data) to parse(tmp) still i'm getting error ; "self.FirstName is not a function inside of the computed function. Any other correction. Here is my new Code

Comment: var PayinyVM = function (data) {
                var self = this;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

                this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                    return self.Name() + " : just ";
                });
            };

            $.getJSON('/service/PaidService.svc/PaidList', function (data) {
                var tmp = JSON.stringify(data.d);

                PayinyVM.model = new PayinyVM(JSON.parse(tmp)); // ko.mapping.fromJSON(tmp);
                ko.applyBindings(PayinyVM);
            });

Comment: @FrenchiInLA - You were new'ing up the model correctly but then assigning it to a property of the PayinyVM function which doesn't make sense. Also there is no need to stringify your json first, it's already a json object why serialize. I've edited the code to fit what you have.

Comment: Thanks again madcap. It makes sense, and i start understanding knockout, but still getting the self.Name is not a function. the data passed is correct,and Name is part of each object of the data, but self is somehow not mapped to this data I will try to make a simple mock file in js,and will let youknow. thanks again, and I really appreciated your help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nYF67/ i just added data the way that i get from WCF.Please take a look at it and let me know what i'm missing. Thanks

Comment: Few issues with your fiddle. The data is not valid json. Pass it to JSONLint and see. Missing knockout in the resources. You were foreaching on a model property that doesn't exist. Here's how it should be. http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/nWTMf/3/ If you are expecting an array of objects then it should be received as { arrayName: [ .. ] }, then your foreach would be on arrayName.

Comment: Also if you want to deal with arrays of objects you should read the docs on the mapping plugin options. You will need a second model object e.g PersonVM.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I have to define all view model properties inside javascript so that knockout can initialize the view model with properties, before I update it with server data

Reference: http://www.underwatergorilladome.com/how-to-use-knockouts-computed-observables-with-the-mapping-plugin/

http://jsfiddle.net/GLDxx/2/

```
var model = {
    username : ko.observable(),
    get_student_info : ko.mapping.fromJS(
        {
            usr_lname : null,
            usr_fname : null,
            gender : null,
            dob : null
        },
        {
            create: function(options) {
                return (new (function () {
                    this.name = ko.computed(function () {
                        if (this.usr_lname == undefined || this.usr_fname == undefined)
                            return null;
                        else
                            return this.usr_lname() + ' ' + this.usr_fname(); 
                    }, this);

                    // let the ko mapping plugin continue to map out this object, so the rest of it will be observable
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
                }));
            }
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: Having spent an hour searching for the answer, this example made everything clear and I now have what I want working :)