# Add computed properties to a view model and its sub items

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm gonna try to make a simplified example of a problem that I have. I think that I'm very close to a solution but I need your help with the finishing touch.

Let's say that I have a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.foo = ko.observable();
    self.bars = ko.observableArray();
}

function bar(data){
    var self = this;
    self.baz = ko.observable();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapperSettings, self);
}
```

I use the [ko.mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to map some data from the server:

```
var mapperSettings = {
     bars: {
        create: function(options) {
            return new bar(options.data);
        }
    }
};    

var dummyData = {
    foo: '1',
    bars: [{ baz: 1 }, { baz: 2 }]
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.mapping.fromJS(dummyData, mapperSettings, vm);
```

So far everything is fine.

Now, I would like to augument the view model and its items with some extra computed properties. I've managed to add it to the view model successfully (`something_computed` below), but I can't manage to add a computed property to a list item - `computed` property on a `bar` item below:

```
var settings = {  
  create: function(options) {

    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
      bars: {
        create: function (options) {
          // why is this callback called 4 times and not 2?
          var self = options.data;

          self.computed = ko.computed(function(){
              return this.baz() + ' comp';
          }, self);

          return self;
        }
      }
    });

    model.something_computed = ko.computed(function(){
      return this.foo() + '...';
    }, model);

    return model;
  }
};

var newViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(vm, settings);

ko.applyBindings(newViewModel);
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s6jsLx1/6/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906252/knockout-mapping-with-computed-fields?

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for the link. As far as I can tell from various SO threads I'm doing the mapping correctly in my last update above. Or did I miss something? I can't wrap my head around why the `create` callback is called more than twice...

Comment: I think you're supposed to have your create function create a new object, not just modify and return what you receive. I don't know why it's calling four times, but the last two times don't have a `baz`, so you can maybe short-circuit them. https://jsfiddle.net/4s6jsLx1/7/

Comment: Yeah I think so too. But regardless, I can't understand why it's being called 4 times. Thanks though

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the mapping code in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tweaked your fiddle and got it working as I think you want it - it is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4s6jsLx1/10/

The main thing I've done is to implement the pattern described below in order to allow you to easily and cleanly define nested view models each with computeds, without your code becoming tied in knots (see note at bottom about create being called 4 times) --

Firstly, create some dummy data, eg

```
data = {foo: 1}
```

Then, create a view model definition for a view model that will hold this dummy data. Define your computed here. You don't normally need to define an observable for `foo` because the mapping plugin will create that for you, but because you reference it from the computed, then in this case, you do need to define it:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this
    self.foo = ko.observable()
    self.computed_foo = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.foo() + " comp"
    })
}
```

Then instantiate this as a blank view model, to get an instance that has the computed:

```
blank_vm = new viewModel()
```

Finally, use ko.mapping to fill it in with the data. This example supplies `{}` as a blank settings object, but in the fiddle I use your proper settings object to create the bars:

```
vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, blank_vm)
```

`vm` now has two properties, `foo` (where `foo() == 1`) and `computed_foo` (where `computed_foo() == "1_comp"`

---

Regarding create being called 4 times, if you replace your console.log with:

```
console.log('create', options.data);
```

then you will see on the 3rd and 4th time it is called, the data passed in is garbage. I did not spend much time working out exactly where it came from but broadly speaking I think your code became a bit tied in knots in terms of how the mappings and computeds were interacting. My solution has removed this create method entirely by following the pattern outlined above, which is intended to keep the creation of computeds separate from the mapping process. Hopefully it does what you need!

Comment: Yes, I noticed the "garbage-part" as well. I think the main problem is that, just as you are implying, I use `ko.mapping.fromJS` along with an already mapped view model instead of some "clean" data like parsed JSON. Pretty obvious when you think about it. Sometimes you need two sets of eyes ;) Thank you for your descriptive answer - I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, glad that worked! I reckon you are right about the cause of the garbage, that makes sense.