# Knockout mapping nested array with computed property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I nees to compute a set of datetimes serverside, allowing to change date/time clientside.
The code below works as per load server data and add the iso field I need back on the server.

How can I make the iso field dynamically computable when the user change the date/time input field?

Knockout JS so far:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    // ...other first-level observables and funct

    function scadenzeNuove(payload) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(payload, {}, this);

    this.iso = ko.pureComputed( function() {
                var data_re = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})T(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
                if (!payload.data) {
                    return false;
                };
                var data_string = payload.data;

                if (!payload.ora) {
                    data_string = data_string + 'T00:00';
                } else {
                    data_string = data_string + 'T' + payload.ora;
                };

                var data_match = data_re.exec(data_string) ? data_re.exec(data_string) : false;
                if (!data_match) { return false; };
                var data = new Date(data_match[3], data_match[2]-1, data_match[1], data_match[4], data_match[5])
                return data;
    }, this);

    };
    var scadenzeNuoveMapping = {
        create: function(options) {
            return new scadenzeNuove(options.data);
        },
    };

    self.scadenzeNuove = ko.observableArray();
    self.compScadenze = function(form) {
    $.getJSON('{{ compute_scadenza }}', $(form).serialize(), function(data){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, scadenzeNuoveMapping, self.scadenzeNuove);
    });
    };
};
var vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Html:

```
<div data-bind="if: scadenzeNuove">
      <ul data-bind="foreach: scadenzeNuove">
        <li>
          <span data-bind="text: iso().toLocaleFormat()"></span>
          <input type="text" name="n_data" data-bind="value: data">
          <input type="text" name="n_ora" data-bind="value: ora">
          <input type="text" name="n_desc" data-bind="value: desc">
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose the issue is that the iso property doesn't get mapped, as the mapping calls happen before... But i don't know how apply the correct timing...

Comment: I tried to use a bare ko.computed as shown in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906252/knockout-mapping-with-computed-fields?rq=1) but still not working: iso field is not updating as components fields values change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault: I referred static data `payload` instead of dynamic observable `parent`:

```
function ScadenzeNuove(payload) {
    var parent = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(payload, {}, parent);

    parent.iso = ko.pureComputed( function() {
        var data_re = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})T(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
        if (!parent.data()) {
            console.log("Not entered any date");
            return false;
        };
        var data_string = parent.data();

        if (!parent.ora()) {
            data_string = data_string + 'T00:00';
        } else {
            data_string = data_string + 'T' + parent.ora();
        };

        var data_match = data_re.exec(data_string) ? data_re.exec(data_string) : false;
        if (!data_match) {
            console.log('Not a valid date format');
            return false;
        };

        console.log(data_match);

        // Array [ "08/06/2017T23:50:00", "08", "06", "2017", "23", "50" ]
        var data = new Date(data_match[3], data_match[2]-1, data_match[1], data_match[4], data_match[5])
        console.log(data.toLocaleFormat());
        console.log(data.getTimezoneOffset());
        return data;
    }, parent);


    parent.toCal = ko.observable(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a default constructor to go from an ISO string to a viewmodel with separated year, month, etc. observables first.

Then, you can define a computed `isoString` property that re-combines these in to a string you can send to the server.

I'd strongly advice you to either write some solid tests or use moment.js if you're working with `Date`s...

```js
const DateTimeSelection = function(isoString) {
  const date = new Date(isoString);
  
  this.year = ko.observable(
    date.getFullYear()
  ).extend({ num: true });
  
  this.month = ko.observable(
    date.getMonth()
  ).extend({ num: true });
    
  this.date = ko.observable(
    date.getDate()
  ).extend({ num: true });
 
  this.hour = ko.observable(
    date.getHours()
  ).extend({ num: true });

  this.isoString = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    new Date(
      this.year(), this.month(), this.date(), this.hour()
    ).toISOString()
  );
  
  this.hasChanged = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    this.isoString() !== isoString
  );
};


ko.extenders.numeric = function(target) {
  return ko.computed({
    read: target,
    write: x => target(Number(x))
  });
};

const initialServerData = "2017-06-16T14:00:00.000Z";
const vm = new DateTimeSelection(initialServerData);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput: year">
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput: month">
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput: date">
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput: hour">



<div data-bind="text: 'output ' + isoString()"></div>
<div data-bind="ifnot: hasChanged" style="color: green">Has not been altered by user</div>
<div data-bind="if: hasChanged" style="color: red">Has been altered by user</div>
```

Comment: My question is about mapping a json array with ko.mapping.fromJS, not to mess with js datetimes more than I'd to

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my views very well... What I was trying to explain is that it's easier to use ISO date strings to communicate between your viewmodels and your server models. I.e.: receive a `DateTime` ISO string, create a viewmodel for it that creates `year`, `month`, etc. inputs and then in the end cast back to an ISO string. Also, I'd say using regex to parse an ISO string is more "mess with js datetimes" than using the language features actually made to solve these kinds of problems...

Comment: Got your point, thanks. However, my code broke because I didn't manage right javascript function scope.